# Custom code for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I would like to know where to enter custom code to change the value of a Label property for a UITableViewCell.

I am not sure how this is loaded, as I have put an NSLog in the ViewDidLoad and (id)initWithStyle instance methods but neither write to the log.

I have setup a NIB and custom class all correctly linked, and the Label is linked as a property and no longer causes an error. But I am unable to setText.

This is how the custom cell is called:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
LeftMenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftMenuTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (LeftMenuTableViewCell*)view;

        }
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

This is the code in the IMP file for the LeftMenuViewCell class.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

displayName.text = [self.user objectForKey:@"displayName"];
```

I can set the displayName to a string and this does not change either. If I add an NSLog to the viewDidLoad for the custom cell class it is not shown, like it is not loaded, but the cell is loaded...?

Comment: Do you want to know how to fill a `UITableView` with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have custom UITableViewCell with UILabel called testLabel. If your NIB and custom class are properly linked than you can use following code:

MyTableViewCell.h

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;

@end
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath in your UITableViewController or UIViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCellId";
      MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil) {
          NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
         cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];    
      }

      [cell.testLabel.text = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

      return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Without code specifics, I can only give a vague'ish answer.

Your custom cell will need to subclass `UITableViewCell`, and you need to provide your table with this custom subclass when the data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I'd suggest reading up on how cells are added/used with `UITableView`s:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Comment: I have added additional information to the question including code examples

Answer (score 0):

**For example**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 RouteCell *routeCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:routeIdentifier];

if (routeCell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RouteCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    routeCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

routeCell.travelTime.text = @"Here you are setting text to your label";

return routeCell;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added code exmaples to the question. I understand that this could be set on the call to the cell itself but I would like the code to be in the imp file for the actual custom cell class, as I will be using multiple custom cells

Comment: Custom cell doesn't have viewDidLoad method, it's only for UIViewController. You should update cell's outlets in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.